# MSBuild giving error related to VS 2010 when I have VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to build a C++ project using MSBuild. The MSBuild I use is from Visual Studio 2017 Community edition installed in my machine. I use CMake 3.8 to generate Visual Studio project files, "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" generator. I build on the command prompt using the call below;

```
msbuild /p:Platform=x64 ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
```

This gives me error message:

```
    error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2010 (Platform Toolset = 'v100') cannot be 
    found.
    To build using the v100 build tools, please install Visual Studio 2010 build tools.
    Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project 
    menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution".
```

When I remove the "/p:Platform=x64" switch the error is gone.
From other questions looks like this is related to 2010 version of Visual Studio. All I have is Visual Studio 2017. What I'm missing? Is the "/p:Platform=x64" switch applicable to MSBuild from Visual Studio 2017? I'm on Windows 10 x64.

Comment: Is there a possible library being referenced that depends on toolset v100?

Comment: @bl4kh4k, I'm using Qt 5.9.1, from the Qt website there is no information on which version of Visual Studio they used for this specific Qt version.

Comment: I think v100 is 2010. Try installing the 64 bit version of c++ redistribution 2010 then recompiling.

Comment: @bl4kh4k, I still get the same error message.

Comment: Does this help? https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/generator/Visual%20Studio%2015%202017.html when specifying host=x64?

Comment: Clearly the error message says "Platform Toolset = 'v100'". Sounds like CMake generates the project file for Visual Studio 2010. You might locate the setting in the project file, and change it to match VS2017.

Comment: You can try to build your project with `cmake --build . --target ALL_BUILD --config Release` in the build directory (i.e. in the directory you called `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"`). If MSBuild is installed correctly it will be used by CMake to build the project.

Comment: I just had a similar problem to this, and the issue was that I'd accidentally deleted a letter from the --config value, so I guess it was pulling in the default config and loading the wrong build tools